# URLLoader share session in AS3 not working in Windows

Tags: apache, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have 1 URLLoader to log the user in, then after the user has logged in successfully, I have another URLLoader which once the user is logged in, it queries back relevant information..

This works perfectly fine on my Mac OSX with MAMP running (when I'm running it as an AIR project), and on CentOS..  But when I try to test it with Windows (WAMP), it doesn't seem to remember the session of the URL-Loader... Any ideas?

Comment: its my suggestion:
please write a log in run-time environment to see what's wrong is in the app.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "share session"? URLLoader only helps you create requests to the server-side

> The URLLoader class downloads data from a URL as text, binary data, or URL-encoded variables. It is useful for downloading text files, XML, or other information to be used in a dynamic, data-driven application.

If you have problem with session in your AIR application, It means you have problem with inner state in your app or on server-side. From information you provided, you should find problems in your session realisation on server-side because of moving logic on WAMP setup. For example, web server doesn't store session etc.